# Need to change value to all cells after C1-BB1 to match B1 if it has a value

Tags: excel, vba, loops

[image]

Need help with this one. New here.
If there is any value in cell C1 thru BB1 then it = Cell B1. But then loop thru the rest of sheet to do the same but value changes to B2 then B3 then B4 and so on.
This is what i have so far.

```
Private Sub AddingValue()
    For Each cell In Range("C1:BB1")
        If cell.Value > 0 Then
            cell.Value = Range("B1").Value
        End If
    Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you want `cell.Value = Range("B" & cell.Row).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the usedrange of the sheet:

```vb
Public Sub AddingValue()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet    '--> adjust this to your needs


Dim rgToCheck as Range
'to start in row 2, you have to offset usedrange by 1 (if data start in row 1)
With ws.UsedRange
     Set rgToCheck = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.count - 1)
End With

Dim c As Range, r As Range
Dim BValue As Variant

For Each r In rgToCheck.Rows 'look into each row
    BValue = r.Cells(, 2)   'store value of column B

   'resize the row range to start at C
    Set r = r.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, r.Columns.Count - 2) 

    For Each c In r.Cells
        If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
            c.Value = BValue
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the UsedRange includes column A?

Comment: you are right - the screenshot looks like this

Comment: Agreed, more of a note to OP. If the `UsedRange` does not include column A, then for example, `r.Cells(, 2)` will not refer to column B.

Comment: Is it possible to make it start on a different row?